# Stuck on a 3d equation

Tags: trigonometry, 3d

I have three 3D points with an known Z value:

```
point 1 = (0, 0, Z1)
point 2 = (64, 0, Z2)
point 3 = (64, 64, Z3)
```

I need an equation to solve for the Z value given an X and Y position within these 3 points. assuming a flat gradient between these points.

thanks in advanced:

Comment: What do you mean by "flat gradient"? You can't guaruntee that the gradient is constant, since 3 points determine a plane, and the 4th may or may not like on that plane.

Comment: yeh fair point. so an equation will only work for 3 points

Comment: Perhaps by "flat gradient" he means that the fourth point lies on the plane spanned by the 3 points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume here you mean that you want a function $z(x,y)$ which tells you the coordinates of a point on the plane given its first two coordinates. This can be done.

For convenience, change coordinates such that one of your points is the origin. For your case we'll do so with the first point, changing to $z'=z-z_1$. Once you have done that, your plane is defined by

$$ax+by+cz'=0$$

You can find the normal by plugging in your points; you get a system

$$\begin{bmatrix} x_1 & x_2 & x_3 \\
y_1 & y_2 & y_3 \\
z'_1 & z'_2 & z'_3 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} a \\ b \\ c \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}.$$

This system will have a nontrivial solution because one of the columns will be all zero, by construction. In higher dimensions you can solve this system by row reduction or similar. In 3 dimensions you can use the cross product of the two nonzero vectors.

Let's work this out for your case. The vectors are

$$(x,y,z')=(0,0,0),(64,0,z_2-z_1),(64,64,z_3-z_1).$$

So the normal is the cross product of $(64,0,z_2-z_1)$ and $(64,64,z_3-z_1)$. This is given by

$$(x,y,z')=(-64(z_2-z_1),64(z_2-z_1)-64(z_3-z_1),4096)=(-64(z_2-z_1),64(z_2-z_3),4096).$$

Changing coordinates back, we have

$$-64(z_2-z_1)x+64(z_2-z_3)y+4096(z-z_1)=0.$$

Rearrange to get

$$z(x,y)=z_1+\frac{64(z_2-z_1)}{4096}x+\frac{64(z_3-z_2)}{4096}y.$$

Comment: really appreciate the help mate thanks.

Answer (score 1):

point 1 = (0, 0, Z1)
point 2 = (64, 0, Z2)
point 3 = (64, 64, Z3)
point 4 = (x,y,Z4) = (x,y,Z2+(64-x)(Z1-Z2)/64+y(Z3-Z2)/64
I use point 2 as the base.  From point 1, we see $z$ changes by $Z1-Z2$ when $x$ changes by $64$.  So I add (64-x)/64 times $(Z1-Z2)$  which matches at both point 1 and point 2.
Again, compare point 2 with point 3, and a change in $y$ of 64 changes $z$ by $Z3-Z2$.  So multiply $y/64$ by $(Z3-Z2)$.

Comment: I am not sure why our answers are so different; I think one or the other of us must be mistaken.

Comment: I think mine fits at the three points, and it is a linear function.

Comment: I think you're right, and there is some problem with the change of coordinates. That said, some explanation to the effect of "this is a linear function which passes through all three points" might be useful here.

Comment: I think you were on the right track, but you shouldn't add $z1$ to the normal's third component.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. I will put it back with that change.

Comment: really appreciate the help mate thanks.